# Why does $\frac{d}{d\nu}\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)$ simplify to digamma function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gamma-function, digamma-function

$$-(\nu+1)\frac{d}{d\nu}\left[\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)-\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)\right]=\frac{\nu+1}{2}\left[\psi\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)\right]$$

How to derive the above equality? I don't understand how taking the derivative of the log gamma function results in the digamma functions and other resulting side-effects. What steps occurred in between?

Comment: By definition, $\psi(z)= \frac{d}{dz} \log \Gamma(z)$. Use this together with the chain rule.

Comment: $\frac{d}{d\nu}\left[\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{2}\psi\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of answering the question we have from the [definition of the polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) and the chain rule:
$$
(\nu+1)\partial_\nu^{n+1}(\log\Gamma(\tfrac{\nu+1}{2})-\log\Gamma(\tfrac{\nu}{2}))=(\nu+1)2^{-n-1}(\psi^{(n)}(\tfrac{\nu+1}{2})-\psi^{(n)}(\tfrac{\nu}{2})),
$$
for which your problem is given by the special case $n=0$.